# Running Cron every 2 hours

Tags: linux, cron

I have the cron job as shown below, and wanted it to run every 2 hours, but it keeps running every 2 minutes.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
  
* */2 * * * /path-to-script
```

Comment: https://crontab.guru/every-2-hours

Answer (score 149, accepted):

An asterisk in the minute (first) field tells it to run every minute, regardless of the other fields.

You need to specify an exact minute to run within the hour. Be that on the hour (0), half past (30), etc..

```
0 */2 * * * /path-to-script
```

Comment: that should do it.

Answer (score 15):

Off the top of my head, you could try specifying all the hours when it should run:

```
0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /path-to-script
```

Comment: */2 is much cleaner

Comment: */2 while cleaner, is not portable... does not work on solaris and likely most other unix variants.

Comment: Good to know. This options has the ability to ignore some of the hours which we may not need to execute the cron.

Answer (score 15):

The correct description of what you had

```
 * */2 * * * /path-to-script
```

is "run every minute where the hour is a multiple of 2".

Which means 00:00 to 00:59, 02:00 to 02:59, 04:00 to 04:59, ... and so on.
Not quite the same as "run every minute".
The solution already given is valid though.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do this:

```
0 0-23/2 * * * /path/to/the/script
```

or if you want to be more specific on every 2 hours, you can use:

```
0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /path/to/the/script
```

The hours values should be separated by commas.

Comment: This should be acepted as well:  `0 0-23/2 * * *`